# TSQL, Get child records for ParentId where condition X

Tags: t-sql

Goal is to retrieve a summary of past due amounts for a user.
The group by clause appears to be the issue as it is required for the SUM function call.
I know that this is possible via a sub query but I would like to avoid this for performance reasons.

```
SELECT      u.Name      AS 'UserName'
        SUM(i.Amount)   AS 'PastDue'
FROM        [User] u
LEFT JOIN   [Invoice] i
ON      i.UserId = u.Id
WHERE       i.DueDate > GETDATE()
AND     i.Paid = 0
GROUP BY ???
```

Table [User]

```
Id  Name
1   John
2   Mike
3   Brian
4   Todd
5   Asyan
```

Table [Invoice]

```
Id  UserId      Amount      DueDate     Paid
1   1       100     1/1/2019    0
2   1       100     1/2/2019    0
3   5       200     1/1/2019    1
4   5       200     1/2/2019    1
5   5       200     1/3/2019    0
```

Expected Result

```
UserName    PastDue
John        200
Asyan       200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query checks for "greater than `GETDATE()`". What you propably meant was `duedate` less than `getdate()`.

The following query should give you the expected result:

```
SELECT u.Name AS 'UserName', 
SUM(i.Amount) AS 'PastDue' FROM [User] u
LEFT JOIN [Invoice] i ON i.UserId = u.Id
WHERE i.DueDate < GETDATE() AND i.Paid = 0
GROUP BY u.Name
```

Comment: Grouping by `User.Id` would: (1) reduce confusion if two users have the same name and (B) ought to perform better since it is matching integers rather than strings. (Assuming there are useful indexes.) And it makes it consistent with the `on` clause of the `join`.